# Google API NodeJS - Getting 401 Unauthorized Error on Subsequent Runs After Successful OAuth2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

On first run when token.js file doesn't exist, I get redirected to localhost:3000 with the `authenticate()` function, and it gets authenticated successfully, afterwards it writes some of credentials to token.js, now on 2nd run, the token.js exist so it will call `loadSavedCredentialsIfExist()`.

Now I get error 401 unauthorized client

Some notes is, I am setting up the Google API on linxu Ubunto and worked perfectly on my windows.
I installed gcloud with default login and default Google credentials and still nothing.

It only gets  get successfully authentication with redirect oAuth2 screen which I don't  always want to do that.

Code below taken from https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/nodejs with some adjustments:

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
const process = require('process');
const {
  google
} = require('googleapis');
const {
  authenticate
} = require("@google-cloud/local-auth");
const {
  GoogleAuth
} = require('google-auth-library');

const SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/', ' https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

// The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
// created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
// time.
const TOKEN_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '/token.json');
const CREDENTIALS_PATH = path.join(__dirname, '/credentials.json');

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
  try {
    const content = await fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH);
    const token = JSON.parse(content);
    // return new GoogleAuth({
    //   client_email: "physio.quantax@gmail.com",
    //   private_key: AIzaSyBIUA-YbbZILxVX-w4A_jUVikuOqlq1dDY,
    //   keyFile: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
    //   keyFilename: CREDENTIALS_PATH,

    //   projectId: "whatsapp-gmail-automation",
    //   scopes : SCOPES
    // })
    return google.auth.fromJSON(token);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
}

/**
 * Serializes credentials to a file compatible with GoogleAUth.fromJSON.
 *
 * @param {OAuth2Client} client
 * @return {Promise<void>}
 */
async function saveCredentials(client) {
  const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
  const keys = JSON.parse(content);
  const key = keys.installed || keys.web || keys;
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    type: 'authorized_user',
    client_id: key.client_id,
    client_secret: key.client_secret,
    refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token || key.refresh_token,
    access_token: client.credentials.access_token,

  });
  await fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, payload);
}


/**
 * Load or request or authorization to call APIs.
 *
 */
const authorize = async () => {
  let client

  client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
  if (client) {
    console.log('********************authorize client:', client)

    return client;
  }


  // client = await authenticate({
  //   scopes: SCOPES,
  //   keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  //   // keyFilename: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  // });

  // console.log('********************authorize client:', client)
  // if (client.credentials) {
  //   await saveCredentials(client);
  // }

  return client;
}

module.exports = {
  loadSavedCredentialsIfExist,
  saveCredentials,
  authorize,
  CREDENTIALS_PATH,
  TOKEN_PATH
}
```